# Generate exact sequence of 35 out of 49 numbers from sample

Tags: java, random, prng

I was wondering if there is any possibility to find out the RNG for the sequences below and accurately predict future sequences. It's an exact sample of 8 bulks of generated numbers containing reference number, date, time to the second and the outcome of 35 comma separated randomly generated numbers. 35 out of 1 to 49. I assume the seed is somehow related to the time. Can these 35 numbers be predicted in the exact order?

Ciprian

Here's the sequence:

35270592    02.07.2015 16:37:30 1, 11, 21, 14, 10, 25, 20, 12, 27, 36, 28, 46, 2, 13, 23, 6, 30, 40, 18, 34, 24, 3, 5, 38, 8, 9, 15, 19, 47, 16, 41, 35, 43, 26, 33

35270591    02.07.2015 16:34:00 27, 33, 4, 26, 47, 21, 48, 28, 42, 49, 24, 32, 14, 44, 29, 15, 39, 35, 41, 10, 34, 45, 18, 30, 43, 8, 6, 19, 40, 2, 31, 3, 7, 9, 23

35270590    02.07.2015 16:30:30 35, 43, 44, 39, 24, 37, 23, 22, 48, 3, 28, 31, 21, 19, 16, 5, 41, 47, 33, 12, 45, 34, 30, 49, 4, 14, 8, 18, 9, 32, 36, 26, 10, 29, 7

35270589    02.07.2015 16:27:00 14, 48, 18, 32, 22, 27, 26, 1, 4, 2, 6, 21, 12, 24, 30, 47, 36, 42, 45, 35, 34, 23, 11, 8, 7, 25, 17, 46, 33, 40, 19, 49, 15, 44, 13

35270588    02.07.2015 16:23:30 35, 23, 43, 6, 5, 49, 21, 14, 18, 47, 40, 11, 1, 26, 4, 39, 34, 44, 37, 31, 29, 24, 33, 2, 20, 41, 25, 42, 36, 10, 28, 32, 19, 8, 48

35270587    02.07.2015 16:20:00 35, 23, 41, 47, 34, 20, 3, 25, 22, 48, 10, 49, 32, 16, 6, 45, 21, 46, 43, 37, 2, 12, 42, 39, 30, 1, 9, 24, 27, 26, 29, 8, 19, 14, 13

35270586    02.07.2015 16:16:30 46, 48, 26, 8, 36, 25, 23, 39, 1, 30, 43, 6, 29, 28, 5, 41, 40, 17, 21, 2, 38, 35, 9, 24, 19, 20, 32, 34, 45, 13, 47, 16, 11, 14, 15

35270585    02.07.2015 16:13:00 16, 33, 20, 21, 43, 35, 26, 39, 18, 37, 44, 47, 28, 48, 17, 15, 19, 6, 14, 22, 46, 4, 8, 31, 41, 12, 9, 49, 2, 3, 11, 25, 10, 30, 40

Comment: It would mean that there's a serious flaw in the RNG if you could do that.

Comment: If you want to attack it, at least make an attempt at reverse-engineering the executable code.

Comment: Very easy to program: once you know the algorithm of the generator, you try all the seeds until you get the sequence you see. (Note: you may need a computer a little faster than you're using now, unless you are using a very old algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator for one thing to try.  At least, a failure will eliminate the chance that the underlying generator is linear congruential.  Even if it is, that will still leave the problem a to how the initial seed is derived from the number and date-time given.